# what is the area of triangle?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $A\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ define an invertible linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^2$. let $T$ be a triangle with one of its vertices at the origin and of area $a$. What is the area of the triangle which is the image of $T$ under this transformation?

I was trying this question, but I could not get any clue and hint. BUT I know that area of triangle $=1/2 \cdot \text{base} \cdot \text{height}$. I don't how this transformation can be shown
I don't know  the solution
if anbody help me I would be very thankful to him

Answer (score 1):

The area is $|\det A|\times a$.

Comment: how it came @ jose carlos santos

Comment: @lomberlego That's a property of the determinant: if $A$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ into itself and if a region $T$ in the domain of $A$ as area $a$, then the area of $A(T)$ is $|\det(A)|\times a$.

Comment: thanks @ jose carlo santos.......u r taking domain as a area or determinant  ,i didn't get the point

Comment: @lomberlego It was a typo and it's too late to edit it. I meant “$A$ has area”, not “$A$ as area”.

Comment: thanks a lot , now i got it @ jose carlos santos

Comment: @lomberlego If that's so, perhaps that you could mark my answer as the accepted one.

Comment: ok actually   i forget it im in hurried@ jose carlos santos

Answer (score 0):

(*It is not impertinent to say  that all the infinitely many triangles having same base and height have the same area*).

By rotations the triangles remain evidently unalterable in their areas; By homotheties, the areas $a$ grow (or decrease) proportionately to the coefficient defining the homothety. In other words,

►If the linear transformation $f$ is a rotation then the area $a$ remains constant.

►If $f(\vec v)=k\vec v$ (homothety) then the area is transformed into $k^2a$.